# How can I get present working directory in a nice string form, $PWD?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am trying to customize a build profile in sublime text editor.

I am aimed to reach the python interpreter in a virtual environment, if I do

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "~/Desktop/generalPyProjects/venv/bin/python -u \"$file\""

}
```

It runs nicely, however, what I want to do is, I want to make the path relative(well, at least semi-relative) so that I can use the same building profile without a change, as long as I am in the root directory of the project. I think looking the below code will tell you what I am trying to achieve.

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "$PWD/venv/bin/python -u \"$file\""

}
```

Here, I am trying to use system variable(at least I call it this way, I am kinda new in Linux world, so wording is probably wrong), instead of the project root folder path. So that I will open project folder via sublime text and using this build profie, I will be able to run my scripts.

However, it turns out that using `$PWD` like this is not working. While I am on the bash, `echo $PWD` gives a nice string form of the present working directory, however I am not sure how to do it in a script.

So, how can I do it?

Comment: Tried to replace `$PWD` by just a dot (`"./venv/bin/python"`)?

Comment: @xenoid now, I am mad at myself..

Comment: Where exactly do you put this JSON? Because `$PWD` works just fine in a shell script.

Comment: @muru the default location, I am not on pc now but, the location is correct I am sure. Using `.` instead of `$PWD` works.

Comment: @muyustan I made an answer from that comment, instead of closing the question unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$PWD` is related to the `cd` command. It refers to the current directory, but possibly by a path that is not normalized.

You need just the current directory, and do not care about the exact path to it.

The current directory is simply called `.` (one dot), just as the parent directory is called `..` (two dots).

So you can replace the `$PWD` by `.` and it should work.